# SourceDataLine delay to much for real time playing (synth)

Tags: java, audio, latency, low-latency, synth

I tried making a synth and it works and I can play music with them. However the first synth that I made had delay and you couldn't play fast songs. So I tried again using `sourceDataline.flush()` method to speed it up. Well it somewhat fixes it but delay is to much. I tried also reducing sample rate but delay is to much.

**Edit**: turns out you can comment the line `keyStateInterface.setFlush(false);`
it improves the delay however you still can't play fast songs

here is the code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class SoundLine implements Runnable{
    KeyStateInterface keyStateInterface;
    public SoundLine(KeyStateInterface arg){
        keyStateInterface=arg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100,8,1,true,false);
        try {
            SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();

            SynthMain synthMain = new SynthMain();

            int v = 0;
            while (true) {
                int bytesAvailable = sourceDataLine.available();

                if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                    int sampling = 256/(64);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[sampling];

                    for (int i = 0; i < sampling; i++) {

                        //bytes[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 127f);
                        float t = (float) (synthMain.makeSound((double)v,44100,keyStateInterface)* 127f);
                        bytes[i] = (byte) (t);
                        v += 1;
                    }
                    if(keyStateInterface.getFlush()){
                        sourceDataLine.flush();
                    }
                    sourceDataLine.write(bytes, 0, sampling);
                    //if(!keyStateInterface.isCacheKeysSame())sourceDataLine.flush();

                    //System.out.println(bytesWritten);
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }

                //System.out.println(bytesAvailable);
                //System.out.println();
                //if((System.currentTimeMillis()-mil)%50==0)freq+=0.5;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){


        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SynthMain {
    double[] noteFrequency = {
            466.1637615181,
            493.8833012561,
            523.2511306012,
            554.3652619537,
            587.3295358348,
            622.2539674442,
            659.2551138257,
            698.4564628660,
            739.9888454233,
            783.9908719635,
            830.6093951599,
            880.0000000000,
            932.3275230362,
            987.7666025122,
            1046.5022612024,
            1108.7305239075,
            1174.6590716696,
            1244.5079348883,
            1318.5102276515,
            1396.9129257320,
            1479.9776908465,
            1567.9817439270,
            1661.2187903198,
            1760.0000000000,
            1864.6550460724,
            1975.5332050245,
            2093.0045224048,
            2217.4610478150,
            2349.3181433393,
            2489.0158697766,
            2637.0204553030,
            2793.8258514640,
            2959.9553816931,
            3135.9634878540,
            3322.4375806396,
            3520.0000000000,
            3729.3100921447,
    };
    boolean[] keys = new boolean[noteFrequency.length];
    public double makeSound(double dTime,double SampleRate,KeyStateInterface keyStateInterface){
        if(keyStateInterface.getSizeOfMidiKey()>0){
            keyStateInterface.setFlush(true);
            for(int i=0;i<keyStateInterface.getSizeOfMidiKey();i++) {
                KeyRequest keyRequest = keyStateInterface.popMidiKey();
                if(keyRequest.getCommand()==-112){
                    if(keyRequest.getVelocity()>0)keys[keyRequest.getArg1()] = true;
                    if(keyRequest.getVelocity()<1)keys[keyRequest.getArg1()] = false;
                    System.out.println(keyRequest.getVelocity());
                }
            }
        }else{
            keyStateInterface.setFlush(false);
        }
        //System.out.println("makeSound");
        double a = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            if(keys[i]){
                a+=Oscillate(dTime,noteFrequency[i],(int)SampleRate);
            }
        }
        return a*0.4;
    }
    public double Oscillate(double dTime,double dFreq,int sampleRate){
        double period = (double)sampleRate / dFreq;
        return Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * (int)dTime / period);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class KeyState implements KeyStateInterface{
    boolean isFlush;
    ArrayList<KeyRequest> keyRequest = new ArrayList<KeyRequest>();
    ArrayList<KeyRequest> midiKeyRequest = new ArrayList<KeyRequest>();

    @Override
    public void pushKey(int keyCode, boolean press) {
        keyRequest.add(new KeyRequest(KeyRequest.KEY,keyCode,press));
    }

    @Override
    public void pushMidiKey(int command, int arg1, int velocity) {
        midiKeyRequest.add(new KeyRequest(KeyRequest.MIDI_KEY,command,arg1,velocity));
    }

    @Override
    public KeyRequest popKey() {
        KeyRequest t = keyRequest.get(keyRequest.size());
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyRequest popMidiKey() {
        KeyRequest t = midiKeyRequest.get(keyRequest.size());
        midiKeyRequest.remove(keyRequest.size());
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSizeOfKey() {
        return keyRequest.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSizeOfMidiKey() {
        return midiKeyRequest.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getFlush() {
        boolean v = isFlush;
        isFlush = false;
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFlush(boolean arg) {
        isFlush=arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have some logical error here midiKeyRequest.get(keyRequest.size()) - how can you get item 5 when the list goes from 0 to 4?? Possibly you copying error but otherwise not possible you would get IndexOutOf Bounds - plus what is this KeyInterface and how does it work?? we dont know is it some hand made stuff you got from some blog???

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dug deep into your code, but perhaps the following info will be useful.

The SourceDataLine.write() method uses a blocking queue internally. It will only progress as fast as the data can be processed. So, there is no need to test for available capacity before populating and shipping `bytes`.

I'd give the SDL thread a priority of 10, since most of it's time is spent in a blocked state anyway.

Also, I'd leave the line open and running. I first got that advice from Neil Smith of [Praxis Live](https://www.praxislive.org/). There is a cost associated with continually rebuilding it. And it looks to me like you are creating a new SDL for every 4 bytes of audio data. That would be highly inefficient. I suspect that shipping somewhere in the range of 256 to 8K on a line that is left open would be a better choice, but I don't have hard facts to back that up that opinion. Neil wrote about having all the transporting arrays be the same size (e.g., the array of data produced by the synth be the same size as the SDL write).

I've made a real-time theremin with java, where the latency includes the task of reading the mouse click and position, then sending that to the synth that is generating the audio data. I wouldn't claim thay my latency down to a precision that allows "in the pocket" starts and stops to notes, but it still is pretty good. I suspect further optimization possible on my end.

I think Neil (mentioned earlier) has had better results. He's spoken of achieving latencies in the range of 5 milliseconds and less, as far back as 2011.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I tried out and latency is lower definetly.

Comment: Althrough it still can't register notes fast enough to play quick songs.

Comment: Perhaps reposting, so people can see the current state of things, perhaps in the code review area since the question is non-specific and is about improving the code. If you post again, put a link in the comments here and I'll check it out, see if I can see further possibilities for improvements.

Comment: ok but either way it definetly reduced the delay. I don't feel it anymore

Comment: The thing is that i got really good delay. But as soon as you start playing little to quick it can't log it fast enough. Also i found this article talking about delay: https://diuf.unifr.ch/main/pai/sites/diuf.unifr.ch.main.pai/files/publications/2007_Juillerat_Mueller_Schubiger-Banz_Real_Time.pdf. If i remove the flush it will jump back to 125 milliseconds every time i release a key.

Comment: also could you link to that article about sourceDataLine ?

Comment: Since SDL is unfamiliar, it's natural to make it the first suspect, but I think the cross-thread messaging may be the real issue here. I'd focus on inspecting messaging from keyboard/mouse input to sound thread. My communications with Neil are scattered. If you search on 'nsigma' at jvm-gaming.org, in the 'java sound openAL' topic, some posts come up but I think they will be of limited value for the current issue. Same with this excellent background article on Java sound http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131